# How To Mirror/Rotate a "fillArc" Drawing?

Tags: java, graphics

So, my situation is that I am drawing a lot of concentric circles, and to make this more efficient I am wanting to only draw 1/8 of the circle and then mirror/rotate the rest of the drawing. To be clear, let's say I have the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
    posX = calcX(i);
    posY = calcY(i);
    length = calcLength(i);
    g2.fillArc(posX, posY, length, length, 0, 45);
}
// mirror/rotate 7 times...
```

Is this even possible? I know you can for an Image, but this seems a lot more tricky.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: g2 is a Graphics2D object.

EDIT 2: So, lets say I have the following slice. Is there a way to take this whole slide (drawn with "fillArc") and copy it 7 times and make a full circle:

[image]

EDIT 3: Fixed code to match what I'm saying.

Comment: You want to create a bitmap with transparency, draw the slice, rotate and paste the slice into the target bitmap seven times while respecting transparency to create a full circle? And you expect this to be MORE efficient than just painting the circle? If it really _would be_ more efficient than the circle painting algorithm would be implemented this way (and thus you wouldn't need to do it manually). It isn't.

Comment: Plus you couldn't use antialiasing or you would get quite ugly artifacts at every seam.

Comment: Well, my thinking was if I draw 1/8 I can just put it down in 7 other places. If there are enough circles, say around 100, would I start to see a benefit?

Comment: Ah, I was worried that might happen.

Comment: If you copy whole circles constructed in several expensive single steps, _maybe_ . Slices & rotating - _very_ improbable that there even can be a perfomance gain. Plus, you know, premature optimisation...

Answer (score 0):

I think g2 is a Graphics2D object? 
Then you can use

```
g2.setTransformation();
```

And use a AffineTransformation to rotate the image. Altough it should be more efficient to use

```
g2.drawOval(...);
```

in order to draw circles.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Made me realise I'd explained it completely wrong! It's actually a bit more tricky, perhaps impossibly so. I made some edits.

Comment: Nothing is impossible. Maybe tricky, inefficient or hard - but never impossible ;)